# laravel 6 + elasticsearch-php 7.6 + xampp: No alive nodes found in your cluster

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch, xampp

I use [elasticsearch-php](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php) in my laravel app with XAMPP.

**Versions:**

- PHP: **7.3**
- Laravel: **^6.2**
- Elasticsearch: **^7.6**

`AppServiceProvider.php` code where I register my custom scout driver:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->app->singleton('elasticsearch', function () {
        return ClientBuilder::create()
                ->setHosts([
                    'http://localhost/scout/public'
                ])
                ->build();
    });

    resolve(EngineManager::class)->extend('elasticsearch', function () {
        return new ElasticSearchEngine(
            app('elasticsearch')
        );
    });
}
```

My custom search engine code:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Search\Engines;

use Laravel\Scout\Engines\Engine;
use Laravel\Scout\Builder;
use Elasticsearch\Client;

class ElasticSearchEngine extends Engine
{
    protected $client;

    public function __construct(Client $client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    /**
     * Update the given model in the index.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection  $models
     * @return void
     */
    public function update($models)
    {
        $models->each(function($model) {
            $params = [
                'index' => $model->searchableAs(),
                'type' => $model->searchableAs(),
                'id' => $model->id,
                'body' => $model->toSearchableArray()
            ];

            $this->client->index($params);
        });
    }
}
```

In my case when I try run command `php artisan scout:import App\User` Elasticsearch package return error with message:

> Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\NoNodesAvailableException  : No alive
>   nodes found in your cluster

[image]

How I can solve my problem? Maybe here problem with hosts or xampp setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, DON’T PANIC :) I think what you don't have Elasticsearch installed. It will take 5 minutes to install Elasticsearch and solve your problem.

**Installation**

- [Download](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch) and unpack the Elasticsearch official distribution.
- Run `bin/elasticsearch` on **Linux** or **macOS**. Run `bin\elasticsearch.bat` on **Windows**.
- Run `curl -X GET http://localhost:9200`

Comment: Wow! I didn't think that for the elasticsearch to work, needed some kind of external program installation. I have now re-imported the indexing table and everything works. Thank you for the answer. @Otabek Mansurov